# How to get values from an array of objects, if there are spaces in properties names?

Tags: javascript

There is an object below:

```
var obj = {“2017-12-13”: {“prop 1”: “value1”, “prop 2”: “value2”}, “2017-12-14”: {“prop 1”: “item1”, “prop 2”: “item2”}};
var arr = Object.values(obj); // Result: [{prop 1: “value1”, prop 2: “value2”}, {prop 1: “item1”, prop 2: “item2”}]
```

The result is incorrect because there are no " " around prop 1 and prop 2. That’s why I’m not able to get values. Do you know how to solve this problem?

How can I get values of prop 1 in a new array? (the desired result: `var myArr = [value1, item1]`)

Comment: The quotes are a syntactic thing (and your syntax is wrong).  You don't actually have a problem.

Comment: @SLaks thank you for reply. But i have the similar syntax in json file with quotes and and spaces in properties names. How should I get values in this situation?

Comment: @Olga — Load the JSON. Parse the JSON. Then it is the same.

Comment: The same way you get values from any other object.  Or are you actually asking how to use bracket notation to use property names with spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process your income data I would use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var obj = {"2017-12-13": {"prop 1": "value1", "prop 2": "value2"}, "2017-12-14": {"prop 1": "item1", "prop 2": "item2"}};

var result = Object.values(obj).map(o => o["prop 1"]); // ["value1", "item1"]
```

Also, on bracket notaion see [MDN Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: not sure why this has a downvote, it is the result OP expects

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure to get your problem but I will try to answer:
per instance you have this array:

```
var obj = {
            "2017-12-13": {"prop 1": "value1", "prop 2": "value2"}, 
            "2017-12-14": {"prop 1": "item1", "prop 2": "item2"}
           };
var arr = Object.values(obj);
```

If you want to get the value of the first item which points to the attribute "prop 1" you should do something like:

```
console.log ( arr[0]["prop 1"] );
//"value1"
```

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: Typically if you have to use a static index you're doing something wrong

Comment: @SterlingArcher
I put a static index just as example since I am not sure which actually is her issue. The way she wants to loop to the items is up to her, can be used .map() as you suggest or any other methods.